# Two HD's, Truecrypt full disk encryption, formatting and installing windows

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-8.1, truecrypt, format

like the title says, I have two physical drives, C: and D;. Both are full disk encrypted with Truecrypt. I would like to format C: and install windows, I'm upgrading from windows 7 to windows 8.1 and want to start fresh.

Do I need to decrypt both drives? C: mounts automatically on boot, but the D: I mount manually after boot. Can I just format c:, then install windows normally, then reinstall Truecrypt and be able to mount D:? Do I need to copy anything from the current C: drive in order to be able to remount the D: drive? I already have everything on C: that I want to keep backed up on an external HD.

TL:DR
I guess my main questions is, will formatting C: affect my access to D: after I get windows installed?
I don't want to spend 3 days decrypting c: if I don't have to.

I'm asking here to double-check things before I take the plunge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the true crypt volume(d:) is encrypted with only password then you can decrypt/mount it anywhere I.e no dependency on c: . You can format c: . If you have a key file to decrypt the d: then just backup that file before touching anything

Comment: I use a password to mount D:. That is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, TrueCrypt volumes are independent of the OS. Hence you can mount your TrueCrypt encrypted volume in any computer where you can run TrueCrypt.